# How can I transport external video stream, instead of the webcam on webrtc session?

Tags: android, websocket, video-streaming, sip, webrtc

I'm working over RTCPeerConnection js. I want to broadcast ip cam stream(M3U/HLS) or any video stream on android platform with webrtc. I dont know how to attach external stream to webrtc session.

Is it possible with webrtc or another realtime protocol api?

Answer (score 2):

You should probably rely on a media server like [Kurento](http://www.kurento.org/) to broadcast video streams from another source than the local webcam.
You can define PlayerEndPoint to read video sources through various protocols (file, HTTP, RTSP), and broadcast them to any client as a WebRTC stream with a WebRtcEndpoint, or as a HTTP stream with a HttpGetEndpoint.

See their architecture here: http://www.kurento.org/docs/current/mastering/kurento_architecture.html

Another media server is [Janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/), but I don't know it.

Answer (score 1):

**If** you can receive data from the camera and display it in a  element, then you can use stream = video.mozCaptureStreamUntilEnded(); to get a MediaStream you can attach to a PeerConnection.

Note: currently Firefox-only; this should be merged into the spec in the near future and eventually supported by Chrome.  Firefox is currently implementing another part of the proposed spec additions: canvas.captureStream().

Note: In general, IP cameras may NOT supply a directly browsable video stream from a URL you can drop into video.src.  You can't get a useable stream from an IP camera that only supplies RTP streams, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you may be able to control a remote ip cam so it will send a basic RTP  stream to an IP:PORT. But webrtc requires many mandatory and optional features to be negotiated in SDP and used on the media path: among them, you have encryption (DTLS-SRTP), ICE, muxing, VP8.

The only way to have an ip cam integrated would be to receive from the ip cam an SDP description already compatible with webrtc for the video media. (RTP/SAVPF profile, with all mandatory webrtc features.) In such case, the ip cam would handle everything on its own and you can just deliver its SDP description to the end-user.

webrtc and media are tightly coupled: in practice, the application that will send media also requires to handle everything, from the negotiation (SDP) to the media level.

I guess webrtc implementation may already exist in some ip cam.

Answer (score 0):

AymericM thanks for the rapid response.
Either I have not understood webrtc issue at all, or I was unable to present what I want to achive.
Webrtc is receiving and transmitting the video received from the camera of my device. I do not suppose that the camera supports all the standarts you have mentioned. Do they?

Let me form a test setup like this;
A pc is broadcasting its camera using VLC (so that I may arrange every setting, transport protocols, codecs,, resolution etc.). My device is at the same network. I want to run webrtc on my device, and I want it to transmit video with it, but not my devices camera, I want the camera of the PC. Whatever format is needed, I may adjust using VLC.
Once succeeded, I may try with real IP cameras and see which ones do work like this.

I think this code may help describing the problem.I'm looking for blablabla method..

```
<button id="openRoom">Open Room</button>
<button id="joinRoom">Join Room</button><br />

<script src="//cdn.webrtc-experiment.com/RTCMultiConnection.js"> </script>
<script>
    var stream = blablabla("http://172.16.180.198:8080/videofeed");
    var connection=new RTCMultiConnection();
    connection.dontCaptureUserMedia = true;
    connection.attachStreams.push(stream, stream);
    connection.attachExternalStream(stream, true);


document.getElementById('openRoom').onclick = function() {
   connection.open();
};
document.getElementById('joinRoom').onclick = function() {
    connection.connect();
};
</script>
```

Comment: You can stream "mp3" file as LIVE input source. You can share WebM file using MediaSource API along with WebRTC data channels. You can use a software application same as ManyCam to capture ip-camera, and use it as LIVE-input source for WebRTC. Such software applications can also be used to mix multiple audios in single input-source which is useful when broadcasting in a class room. I donno if mozCaptureStreamUntilEnded can be used as LIVE-input source for RTCPeerConnection API.